# guess sum of two dices

Tags: probability

> A and B roll a 6-faced fair dice respectively. Each one only know his own number after rolling. Based on their numbers, they can guess a number of sum and the higher one will be paid for the real sum with the cost of his guessing number. E.g. A roll 3, B roll 5, the real sum is 8. Now A guess 4, B guess 9. B>A, then B will be paid the real sum 8 with cost his guess number 9, i.e. B will lose 1. What's the expected value of this game?

My idea is that if we know the sum is x, then we will guess x-1. Now there are 1/36 probability that A roll a and B roll b. For A, he know there are 1/6 probability that sum will be a+1, a+2, ... a+6, respectively. So he will guess a, a+1, ..., a+5 with probability 1/6 respectively. Under the same reason, B will guess b, b+1, ..., b+5 with probability 1/6 respectively. Finally we enumerate all the 36*36 pairs:

$$E=\dfrac{1}{36*36}\sum\limits_{a,b=1}^6\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^5 pay(a+i,b+j).$$

Am I correct? And is there any simply way to compute?

Comment: Expected value usually works with purely random events, but it looks like A and B have choices. Are you looking for a strategy for one of the players that maximizes the expected value (of their winnings, or the difference in winnings)? Or do you know A and B's strategies, and you're looking to compute the expected value?

Comment: @Angelica we can regard as the expected value of A under his optimal strategy (here I think the only 'optimal strategy' is just if we know the sum is x, then we will guess x-1).

Comment: I don't think you can consider that the optimal strategy because you don't know the sum, $x-1$ doesn't mean anything.

Comment: This problem is more of a game theory problem with some random elements. In game theory it is very important to specify the exact rules of the game. Are they guessing the sum simultaneously, or is one player guessing first and the second player may observe the first players guess? Are you looking for a Nash equilibrium (i.e. a situation where both players strategies maximize expected individual payoff conditional on the other player's strategy) in this game?

Comment: Or are you looking for the optimal "cartel" solution in which the two players cooperate (in this case they should both guess the lowest possible allowed guess (2?) and the expected payoff is 7-2=5 (however, you need to specify the rules for what happens when both guess the same sum).

Answer (score 0):

A long comment rather than an answer.

Assuming both A and B play intelligently, the optimal strategy would be same for both the players as the game is independent of order of roll and players know only their numbers.

Let's say for a player rolling $X$, $f(X)$ is the prediction based on optimal strategy. Also, let $X$ and $Y$ be the rolls of A and B.

Sum of the dice ($S$) = $X+Y$ and their predictions are $X+f(X)$ and $Y+f(Y)$. Note that each of the player is sure that the sum is atleast larger than their rolled number.

$$
E[Reward] = E[S-\max(X+f(X), Y+f(Y))]\\
E[Reward] = 7 - E[\max(X+f(X), Y+f(Y))]
$$

One interesting case,
**Case** - $f$ is a constant $E[Reward] = 7 - E[\max(X, Y) + c] = 7 - \frac{161}{36} - c$ 
Hence, one would want $c=0$ and Expected Reward = $\frac{91}{36}$.
$c < 0$ Also seems valid meaning that both A and B can agree to say a large negative number $-\infty$ and get huge reward ($+\infty$).

Comment: For the note at the end, I don't think you can assume that A and B will cooperate (even if this was a repeated game).

Comment: Interesting! They also may not agree for $c=0$ and end up till $c=\frac{91}{36}$. After which they will definetly stop as they start making loss.

Comment: here ‘reward’ is the sum of expected payoffs of A and B (one of them will be 0). Shouldn't we compute the payoff of A? (X+f(X)>Y+f(Y))? S-(X+f(X)) : 0.